# Java 8: Get Consumer<?> underlying function annotation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is there any way to access the annotations of the method on a Consumer expression?

```
public void <T> addListener(Consumer<T> consumer)
{
    consumer.getClass().getAnnotation(Handler.class); // Like this
}

@Handler
public void myListener(Integer x) {
}

addListener<Integer>(this::myListener);
```

Comment: Given that `Consumer<T>` is a functional interface, and as a result it can be assigned lambdas - and you can't give lambdas annotations - reason would state no, but I'll wait for someone else to clarify for sure

Comment: Note that you are calling `getAnnotation` on a `Class` instance, not on a `Method` instance (which would be required if this worked).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can the method instance be access with reflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you get is not an instance of your class with the `@Handler`-annotated method. This should be obvious—that class doesn't even implement `Consumer`. You get an ad-hoc implementation of `Consumer` whose `accept` method *delegates* to `myListener()`. Therefore the answer to your question is "no" on purely conceptual grounds.